Self-referencing objects inside functions on print composer
I'm writing a function to display different intervals on a map grid depending on its scale, something like this:

This function is applied to and references the map called "Mapa_principal_R." The issue is that I will need to insert this code into other maps, but I will have to modify it to match the name of each map (around 50 maps or so). So, I was wondering if it's possible to self-reference a map/object without necessarily using its given name or ID. This is a problem I’ve encountered before, having to change either the names of objects (which are usually different so people can differentiate them) or the code to match them, and unfortunately, this is very time-consuming.
Any thoughts on this?

You don't need to use map_get(item_variables(name_of_the_map)).
There is a variable called @map_scale, which is the scale of the map for which you want the grid.
